# PHP Stripslash doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

in my MySQL table I got the comment:

```
"{"out_user":"pb","out_email":"1test@test.de","out_date":"13.04.2015"}"
```

The code I am using is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($coni, "SELECT table_comment FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name='$tablename'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
$head = $row->table_comment;
echo json_encode(stripslashes($head));
```

The output is still:

```
"\"out_user\":\"pb\",\"out_email\":\"1test@test.de\",\"out_date\":\"13.04.2015\"}"
```

Why doesn't `stripslahes` work?

Comment: that's because you're json_encoding what is already json. that requires the "inner" json be completely escaped. e.g. if you weren't chaining your function calls, you'd have seen this: `var_dump($head); $temp = stripslashes($head); var_dump($temp); var_dump(json_encode($temp));`

Comment: There are no slashes in `$head`, so there's nothing to strip. The slashes are being added by `json_encode()`. It needs to do that to encode the quotes in the value.

Comment: oh thanks, to much work today.. thank you both.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman There is nothing here to suggest that `$tablename` is data from an external user/system, and thus a potential vector for SQL injection.  That being said, a programmer should be aware of parametrized prepared statements as an important tool in their tool box.

Comment: @MikeBrant Assumptions are what get people into trouble, so parameterize *everything* you can. What holds true today for "safe" has a tendency to change in the future, and then you're going to regret not doing it properly the first time. Taking a casual approach to this sort of stuff has cost many a company and programmer dearly.

Comment: @tadman But blindly stating "use parametrized prepared statements for everything" is not a good approach either. I would agree that in probably most cases it is the right thing to do, but experienced programmers will know that they are good cases for not using them as well. Prepared statements are not just for prevention against SQL attacks, and do have different performance considerations.

Comment: @MikeBrant If you're working on a system at scale and the performance penalty is an issue, you probably have other bigger issues to deal with. Please, don't confuse the issue here. A beginner **absolutely** should parameterize everything possible. If they have a very good reason for not doing that, fine, but 99% of the time their reason is "laziness" and that doesn't cut it in today's internet environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is *escaped quotes*, where `"\""` is a double quote that's quoted. For the language to differentiate between quotes that terminate your string and quotes that are a part of your string the backslash character is necessary. The backslash character is introduced by the JSON encoding, so your `stripslashes` is operating at the wrong point to grab those.

I think what you're seeing here is you're JSON encoding a pre-existing JSON string for no apparent reason. If you removed the re-encoding part it'd probably produce what you expect.

If you're dealing with already JSON-encoded data, just output it as-is, no mangling or handling required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the correct way is decode and not encode...

```
var_dump( json_decode( $head ) );
```

or simply

```
var_dump( $head );
```